# nLog log API missing requests when deployed on server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, nlog

I have a separate log API using nLog to save logs to a database. It works fine on localhost, but when deployed on the server, some requests (e.g., error, trace) are missing from the database and does not appearing in IIS request queue.

Deployment Environment:

- Server: OS, IIS Server
- nLog Configuration: NLog.Extensions.Logging 5.0.4, NLog.Web.AspNetCore 5.1.4

Problem Description:

- Are these missing requests consistent or intermittent?
- Any observed patterns or specific types of requests missing?

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- Checked server logs, nLog configurations, and database logs.

Specific Requests for Help:

- Are there additional diagnostic steps I should take in a production environment?
- How can I ensure all log requests are properly handled when deployed?

Any assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

- Are there additional diagnostic steps I should take in a production environment?
- How can I ensure all log requests are properly handled when deployed?

Comment: Do not link to files and code, include the relevant parts as text. Ideally in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: You can try using failed request tracing to see details information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: When troubleshooting NLog then it is a good idea to enable `throwConfigExceptions="true"` and also enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting